# Odd and even functions when applying the Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Thank you for any help and tips!
[image]

Edit: I realized after reading H. H. Rugh comment, even thought I still used the upper semi-circle, that I can just expand the second integral of the right hand side of the very first equation and do the following, which does give me the correct answer. Thank you!
[image]

After the complete expansion of the second integral it was easier to see why the sine function was odd.

Comment: i don't see any sin function ?!

Comment: expanding the exponential complex functions gives you the sine functions. These are complex functions.

Comment: You don't specify the contours that you use. Given your last result it looks as if you are simply using the wrong contour for the half circle. You should use the one in the lower halfplane where the exponential goes to zero (fast).

Comment: I used the upper semi-circle. I'll see how it goes then, let me check out the result with the lower half.